# Ionic 3 floating element top location below the Navbar?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to put an element that stays above other elements. Imaging a floating toolbar above an image view. I could achieve it using CSS (is this the recommended way?), but the problem is that that element is below the Navbar.

```
z-index: 20; position:fixed; top:0; left:0;
```

So, I put some hard-coded top.

```
z-index: 20; position:fixed; top:50px; left:0;
```

This looks good on **my** phone, but we all know this is not a good way. I would like to use relative position below the Navbar, like 5% of the height below the Navbar. How can I do that?

PS: Visualisation of what I am saying.
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I cannot "imagine what a floating toolbar above an image view" is.  Can you attach a picture of what this is supposed to look like or a [https://stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: what happens when it is `relative` with `top:0`? also what position does the `Navbar` have?

Comment: Nothing fancy. See [this screenshot](http://android-coffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/cover.jpg) (not mine); there are buttons floating on the image view. I would like to do something like that. The Navbar is at its default position, top. When I tried relative and top:0, the control disappeared (not shown as intended).

Comment: Please see the OP. I have added an illustration.

Comment: Ever heard of the css property 'view height' ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp